# where should android app data be store to prevent loss?

Tags: android, json, storage

I am developing an app that stores user's inputs in a database and I am wondering about the best way to handle it.  I want the info to be retained when the app closes and also when the app gets updates.  The shared preferences feature does not seem like a good idea because the data is more complex (like a JSON file with multiple levels).  Is it safe to simply store the JSON data as a .txt file in internal storage? (i.e. safe from loss...I'm not worried about security).  Here is an example of the JSON data I want to save:

`{
  "Altimeter": "3015", 
  "Cloud-List": [
    [
      "FEW", 
      "025"
    ], 
    [
      "SCT", 
      "055"
    ], 
    [
      "SCT", 
      "200"
    ], 
    [
      "BKN", 
      "250"
    ]
  ], 
  "Dewpoint": "21", 
  "Flight-Rules": "VFR", 
  "Meta": {
    "Cache-Timestamp": "Sun, 26 Aug 2018 16:07:47 GMT", 
    "Timestamp": "Sun, 26 Aug 2018 16:07:52 GMT"
  }, 
  "Other-List": [], 
  "Raw-Report": "KJFK 261551Z 20009KT 10SM FEW025 SCT055 SCT200 BKN250 26/21 A3015 RMK AO2 SLP210 T02560206", 
  "Remarks": "RMK AO2 SLP210 T02560206", 
  "Remarks-Info": {
    "Dew-Decimal": "20.6", 
    "Temp-Decimal": "25.6"
  }, 
  "Runway-Vis-List": [], 
  "Station": "KJFK", 
  "Temperature": "26", 
  "Time": "261551Z", 
  "Units": {
    "Altimeter": "inHg", 
    "Altitude": "ft", 
    "Temperature": "C", 
    "Visibility": "sm", 
    "Wind-Speed": "kt"
  }, 
  "Visibility": "10", 
  "Wind-Direction": "200", 
  "Wind-Gust": "", 
  "Wind-Speed": "09", 
  "Wind-Variable-Dir": []
}`

Answer (score 0):

saving in a textfile is a good way to save the data. The data will not get loss when you take care about the file destination. It shouldn´t be places in any temp folder for example.

Another approach is using a database to store the data. That´s the normal way to do.

Following options you have:
1. SharedPreferences
2. Textfile
3. Database

Tutorials on all the 3 approaches you can find through quick google searches.

Great Coding!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to save data in the SharedPreferences as JsonString, and when retreiving data convert the json to its original object (serialize and deserialize) using Gson library as following:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(yourNeededObject);
SharedPreferences shp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
shp.edit().putString(key, json).apply();
```

and to deserialize:

```
String json = shp.getString(key);
YourObject obj = new Gson().fromJson(json, YourObject.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in safety from loss of this app data, consider remote location, i.e. location off the device. Nowadays any cloud storage will give you that kind of safety.